# error: 'ListView_GetHeade' was not declared in this scope, but i include "commctrl.h" as i see on msdn page

Tags: c++, listview, scope, get-headers

hi i use c++ code blocks.
and i try to get the heade of a listview with ListView_GetHeade():

```
BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{
    int length = ::GetWindowTextLength( hwnd ); //get the length of handler title.
    if( 0 == length ) return true;

    TCHAR* buffer;
    buffer = new TCHAR[ length + 1 ];
    memset( buffer, 0, ( length + 1 ) * sizeof( TCHAR ) );

    GetWindowText( hwnd, buffer, length + 1 ); //get the name of the handler.
    std::wstring str1 (buffer);
    std::wstring str2 (L"יומן חשבוניות"); //set the value to search.
    std::string::size_type found = str1.find(str2); //searching for name.
    if (found!=std::string::npos)
    {
        LPCWSTR rrr = str1.c_str();
        MessageBoxW(hwnd, rrr , L"the file is:", MB_OK);
        HWND w = ListView_GetHeader(hwnd);
        MessageBoxW(hwnd, (LPCWSTR)w , L"text 1:", MB_OK);
```

hwnd is the handle of the window "יומן חשבוניות":
[image]

but it give me the error:

```
error: 'ListView_GetHeader' was not declared in this scope|
```

i include in the head of the code:

```
#include <Commctrl.h>
```

as i see on msdn page : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761290(v=vs.85).aspx

how i solve it?

Comment: Check your spelling!

Comment: You are missing the `r` in `ListView_GetHeader`

Comment: tnx i pix it and it still give me the error...

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: i give some more code, i search for the window "יומן חשבוניות", and then want to get the header of "חשבוניות"